# Rails server not working rails 4.2.6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, localhost, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I made an ruby on rails application on my Mac using rails 4.2.6 and typed `rails server` into terminal. It looked all fine until I went to localhost:3000 in Google Chrome.

The error was:

## This site can't be reached

**localhost** refused to connect

`ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

The output I get when I type `rails s` into terminal is:

```
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.2.6 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/Users/kids/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:275:in `check_part': Missing :controller key on routes definition, please check your routes. (ArgumentError)
    from /Users/kids/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:255:in `check_controller_and_action'
    from /Users/kids/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:178:in `normalize_options!'
    from /Users/kids/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:100:in `initialize'
    from /Users/kids/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:78:in `new'
    from /Users/kids/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:78:in `build'
    from /Users/kids/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1560:in `add_route'
    from /Users/kids/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1537:in `decomposed_match'
    from /Users/kids/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1518:in `block in match'
    from /Users/kids/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1508:in `each'
    from /Users/kids/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1508:in `match'
    from /Users/kids/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:690:in `map_method'
    from /Users/kids/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:651:in `get'
    from /Users/kids/Desktop/PythonApp/config/routes.rb:2:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/kids/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:432:in `instance_exec'
    from /Users/kids/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:432:in `eval_block'
    from /Users/kids/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:410:in `draw'
    from /Users/kids/Desktop/PythonApp/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/kids/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
    from /Users/kids/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
    from /Users/kids/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/kids/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
    from /Users/kids/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `block in load_paths'
    from /Users/kids/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `each'
    from /Users/kids/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `load_paths'
    from /Users/kids/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:16:in `reload!'
    from /Users/kids/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:26:in `block in updater'
    from /Users/kids/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:75:in `call'
    from /Users/kids/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:75:in `execute'
    from /Users/kids/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:27:in `updater'
    from /Users/kids/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:7:in `execute_if_updated'
    from /Users/kids/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:69:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
    from /Users/kids/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /Users/kids/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /Users/kids/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /Users/kids/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:226:in `block in tsort_each'
    from /Users/kids/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:348:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/kids/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:429:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /Users/kids/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:347:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/kids/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each'
    from /Users/kids/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `call'
    from /Users/kids/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/kids/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:224:in `tsort_each'
    from /Users/kids/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:203:in `tsort_each'
    from /Users/kids/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /Users/kids/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
    from /Users/kids/Desktop/PythonApp/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/kids/Desktop/PythonApp/config.ru:3:in `require'
    from /Users/kids/Desktop/PythonApp/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
    from /Users/kids/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
    from /Users/kids/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
    from /Users/kids/Desktop/PythonApp/config.ru:in `new'
    from /Users/kids/Desktop/PythonApp/config.ru:in `<main>'
    from /Users/kids/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
    from /Users/kids/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
    from /Users/kids/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
    from /Users/kids/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:299:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
    from /Users/kids/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:208:in `app'
    from /Users/kids/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:61:in `app'
    from /Users/kids/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:336:in `wrapped_app'
    from /Users/kids/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:139:in `log_to_stdout'
    from /Users/kids/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:78:in `start'
    from /Users/kids/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in `block in server'
    from /Users/kids/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
    from /Users/kids/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
    from /Users/kids/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /Users/kids/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/kids/Desktop/PythonApp/bin/rails:9:in `require'
    from /Users/kids/Desktop/PythonApp/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/kids/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-1.6.4/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
    from /Users/kids/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-1.6.4/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
    from /Users/kids/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-1.6.4/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    from /Users/kids/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-1.6.4/lib/spring/client.rb:28:in `run'
    from /Users/kids/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-1.6.4/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/kids/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-1.6.4/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
    from /Users/kids/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-1.6.4/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/kids/Desktop/PythonApp/bin/spring:13:in `require'
    from /Users/kids/Desktop/PythonApp/bin/spring:13:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

Here is my routes file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    get '/index' => 'welcome#index'
    get '/' => 'welcome#index'
    get '/welcome' => 'welcome#index'

    get 'signup' => 'users#new'
    resources :users

    get '/learn/' => 'learn#hub'

    get '/login' => 'sessions#new'
    post 'login' => 'sessions#create'

    get '/logout' => 'sessions#destroy'
    delete 'logout' => 'sessions#destroy'

  # The priority is based upon order of creation: first created -> highest priority.
  # See how all your routes lay out with "rake routes".

  # You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
  # root 'welcome#index'

  # Example of regular route:
  #   get 'products/:id' => 'catalog#view'

  # Example of named route that can be invoked with purchase_url(id: product.id)
  #   get 'products/:id/purchase' => 'catalog#purchase', as: :purchase

  # Example resource route (maps HTTP verbs to controller actions automatically):
  #   resources :products

  # Example resource route with options:
  #   resources :products do
  #     member do
  #       get 'short'
  #       post 'toggle'
  #     end
  #
  #     collection do
  #       get 'sold'
  #     end
  #   end

  # Example resource route with sub-resources:
  #   resources :products do
  #     resources :comments, :sales
  #     resource :seller
  #   end

  # Example resource route with more complex sub-resources:
  #   resources :products do
  #     resources :comments
  #     resources :sales do
  #       get 'recent', on: :collection
  #     end
  #   end

  # Example resource route with concerns:
  #   concern :toggleable do
  #     post 'toggle'
  #   end
  #   resources :posts, concerns: :toggleable
  #   resources :photos, concerns: :toggleable

  # Example resource route within a namespace:
  #   namespace :admin do
  #     # Directs /admin/products/* to Admin::ProductsController
  #     # (app/controllers/admin/products_controller.rb)
  #     resources :products
  #   end
end
```

When I try rake routes, it says:

```
rake aborted!
ArgumentError: Missing :controller key on routes definition, please check your routes.
/Users/kids/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:275:in `check_part'
/Users/kids/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:255:in `check_controller_and_action'
/Users/kids/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:178:in `normalize_options!'
/Users/kids/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:100:in `initialize'
/Users/kids/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:78:in `new'
/Users/kids/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:78:in `build'
/Users/kids/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1560:in `add_route'
/Users/kids/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1537:in `decomposed_match'
/Users/kids/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1518:in `block in match'
/Users/kids/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1508:in `each'
/Users/kids/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1508:in `match'
/Users/kids/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:690:in `map_method'
/Users/kids/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:651:in `get'
/Users/kids/Desktop/PythonApp/config/routes.rb:2:in `block in <top (required)>'
/Users/kids/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:432:in `instance_exec'
/Users/kids/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:432:in `eval_block'
/Users/kids/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:410:in `draw'
/Users/kids/Desktop/PythonApp/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/kids/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
/Users/kids/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
/Users/kids/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
/Users/kids/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
/Users/kids/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `block in load_paths'
/Users/kids/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `each'
/Users/kids/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `load_paths'
/Users/kids/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:16:in `reload!'
/Users/kids/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:26:in `block in updater'
/Users/kids/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:75:in `call'
/Users/kids/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:75:in `execute'
/Users/kids/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:27:in `updater'
/Users/kids/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:7:in `execute_if_updated'
/Users/kids/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:69:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
/Users/kids/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/Users/kids/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/Users/kids/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/Users/kids/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/Users/kids/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
/Users/kids/Desktop/PythonApp/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/kids/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in `require'
/Users/kids/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in `require_environment!'
/Users/kids/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/application.rb:457:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
Tasks: TOP => routes => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: Startup logs please.

Comment: give the error log after trying to run `rails s`

Comment: I am sort of a noob so what is a startup log?

Comment: Terminal gives me no errors. just chrome.

Comment: hmm, what exactly u getting when running `rails s` in a terminal. Can u pass it here.

Comment: try `bundle install` and check your `routes.rb` file under /config/routes.rb.

Comment: also make sure to run `rake db:migrate` if you have any model. Let me know.

Comment: Can you post `config/routes.rb` and the results of `rake routes`?

Comment: Did you check your routes like it tells you to? As requested, post your routes file. I'm not sure why you think the terminal isn't showing any errors.

Comment: Where is your `/index` route going?

Comment: That's probably where I messed up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I messed up in one of the controllers and in the routes files. All good. IT WORKS!!!

Comment: glad, fixed it. Told u earlier check out `routes.rb` file.